# How do I fix my hexagons that are showing as strange shape with ctx.lineTo in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, polygon

I am trying to create a hexagon on the canvas. I am successfully drawing a shape, but not the correct one. I made a triangle using this same code snippet, I just changed the number of sides.

It looks like each line of the hexagon is getting drawn from the same point instead of from the last point drawn.

I am following a tutorial online that involves creating these shapes. I copied and pasted what the guy in the video did and I typed exactly what he did. I went back multiple times in the video trying to figure out if I missed something.

In the code, is my entire class for creating the hexagon. SOMETHING is getting rendered and drawn, but it is not the correct shape.

I have tried changing some numbers around, and looking into ctx.lineTo to see if I was doing something wrong. I went back and forth in the video while he was creating these shapes and his just worked. I am confident I have the same code as the one in the video for creating the hexagon.

```
class Asteroid {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.visible = true;
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasWidth);
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasHeight);
    this.speed = 1;
    this.radius = 50;
    this.angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359);
    this.strokeColor = gameColor;
  }
  Update() {
    let radians = (this.angle / Math.PI) * 180;
    this.x += Math.cos(radians) * this.speed;
    this.y += Math.sin(radians) * this.speed;
    if (this.x < this.radius) {
      this.x = canvas.width;
    }
    if (this.x > canvas.width) {
      this.x = this.radius;
    }
    if (this.y < this.radius) {
      this.y = canvas.height;
    }
    if (this.y > canvas.height) {
      this.y = this.radius;
    }
  }
  Draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    let vertAngle = (Math.PI * 2) / 6;
    var radians = (this.angle / Math.PI) * 180;
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(
        this.x - this.radius * Math.cos(vertAngle * i + radians),
        this.y - this.radius * Math.sin(vertAngle * i + radians)
      );
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the shape to be a regular hexagon, but instead, I am getting a shape where each line is getting drawn from one point, like a fan or a leaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `closePath` ( which is a lineTo enter point in sub-path, hence all the lines to the first point you got ) and `stroke` only once, after your for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  ctx.lineTo(
    this.x - this.radius * Math.cos(vertAngle * i + radians),
    this.y - this.radius * Math.sin(vertAngle * i + radians)
  );
}
// once all the points have been drawn
ctx.closePath(); // Last closing line
ctx.stroke(); // paint
```

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy trying to figure that out. I didn't even think those two functions were in the wrong curly braces.